# Problem in Dropdown size in jquery

Tags: jquery

Im using jquery to set a dropdown based on selected value from another dropdown.

Fot that Im using following jquery

```
$("#whse").html('<option selected value="">'+value+'</option>'+'\n');
```

The problem is dropdown 2 size decreasing every time when i select the value of dropdown 1

Comment: Hi yes I have specified the width

Comment: Did you try change width after dropdown modification?

Comment: could you provide an example, may be in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: <SELECT id="whse" name="whse" size="1"
style="width: 100%">
<option>All</option>...In jquery im changing the option value like I posted earlier

Comment: $("#whse").html('<option selected value="">'++value+'</option>'+'\n').css('width', '100%');

Comment: use the width in px not in %. Follow the link (http://www.jsfiddle.net), create a free account then copy your code. then post the url in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the second dropdown is not decreasing i think, it's reduced just to a single option because with:

```
$("#whse").html('<option selected value="">'+value+'</option>'+'\n');
```

you are setting the html of the select to that single option. you should use:

```
$("#whse").append('<option selected value="">'+value+'</option>');
```

if you want to add that option

or

```
 $("#whse").val(value)
```

if you want to select the option with that value

Comment: Hi $("#whse").val(value) is not working.I could be able to prevent that using $("#whse").html('<option selected value="">'++value+'</option>'+'\n').css('width', '250');..But the dropdown size increased only one times.I hope that can be avoided by using correct px value.Thanks all!!!

Comment: If the question is answered, accept the answer, if you still have problems, please post them so we can help!